# Converter character com precisão

Tags: r

Considerando que o conteúdo de uma certa variável seja `"001"` de classe *character*.

Preciso transformar tal caractere para numérico. Se faço `as.numeric()`, ele me retorna `1`.

Eu quero que me retorne exatamente 001, é possível?

Obrigado.

Comment: 001 não é exatamente um número, talvez você devesse trabalhar com texto mesmo. Se disser qual objetivo pretende atingir que precisa do 00 na frente talvez alguém possa te ajudar.

Comment: Na verdade, eu tenho uma base de dados onde uma das colunas chamase "Codigos" . Nessa coluna eu tenho caracteres dessa forma. Por exemplo, "00010" , "01234" . Eu preciso selecionar desse banco de dados as linhas que tenham certos códigos.. por exemplo, quero seleccionar somente as linhas de codigos "00010" e "00020". Na hora que eu faço algo tipo desp2<- desp2[ desp2$codigo == "00020" | "00020",] me da um erro, pois esse operador lógico não funciona com caracteres. Por isso a minha necessidade de converter a numerico

Comment: O melhor é trabalhar com carateres mesmo.

Comment: modifiquei meu comentario anterior... agora acho que está mais claro aquilo que eu quero

Comment: Como está o tipo do seu campo "Codigos" no seu BD? Se ele não for numérico não vai adiantar muita coisa buscar com numéricos.

Comment: Boa tarde @Vasco, mas não seria melhor adaptar o banco, modificando a coluna para numérico?

Comment: Vasco, o `==` deveria estar funcionando normalmente, mesmo sendo `character`. O problema provavelmente é outra coisa, se você colocar um exemplo dos dados e do código fica mais fácil ajudar, abs.

Comment: quero transformar essa coluna em numerica.Eu tive uma sol,  adicionei o dígito 1 em todas as linhas da coluna codigo como primeiro dígito. Assim, ma hora de transformar character para numerico, não perco sua localizacao original.Mas mesmo assim, na hora que eu faço desp2<- desp2[ desp2$codigo_novo == 1049 | 1001,]  parece que a seleção não é bem sucedidada, pois o numero de linhas acaba sendo o mesmo. Por outro lado, quando faço desp2<- desp2[ desp2$codigo_novo ==  1001,] a seleção é bem sucedida, pois o número de linhas é menor.

Comment: Galera, @CarlosCinelli .. consegui solucionar meu problema usando a funcao subset mesmo com characater... obrigado galera

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema está no `==` e não na classe. O `==` funciona somente para um valor. Para comparar com mais de um valor, tem que ser `%in%`. No seu caso:

```
desp2[desp2$codigo_novo %in% c('1049', '1001'),]
```

Da mesma forma no subset:

```
subset(desp2, codigo_novo %in% c('1049', '1001'))
```

Usando o `==`, seria necessario duas comparações:

```
desp2$codigo_novo == '1049' | desp2$codigo_novo == '1001'
```

Comment: E se eu quiser usar uma sequencia de códigos? Por exemplo, preciso selecionar as linhas cujos códigos são, continuamente, de "1049" até "1080" ... Como eu faria para evitar escrever código por código?

Comment: Da para usar `codigo_novo %in% 1049:1090` (1049:1090 retorna um vetor com os inteiros entre 1049 e 1090). Apesar de ser número, vai ser transformado em string na hora da comparação. Note que só vai funcionar pois o número possui 4 caracteres, se tiver menos terá que usar o `sprintf()` para acrescentar os 0 a esquerda (Ex: `sprintf('%04d', c(1, 10, 100, 1000))`)